# keeping the footer at the bottom, but not fixed

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, footer

I am trying to make a footer for my site, it's a partial and I render it below the <%= yield %> in the body tags of the application.html.erb file in the layout. It's at the bottom when the page loads but when you scroll to the bottom it stays in the middle of the page. Such a common problem I know. There are so many duplicate questions like this out there but I have yet to find a solution. I set the body and html to 100% height and defined the height for the footer as a certain amount of pixels and set the position to absolute. That didn't do it. Here's what I have:

application.html.erb

```
  <body>


    <%= yield %>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
```

_footer.html.erb

```
<div id="footer">
  Books4Reviews © 2018 All Rights Reserved
</div>
```

application.scss

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 700px) {
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Footer */

#footer {
  bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Did you want your footer to be persistent, always visible at the bottom of the page while you scroll?

Comment: No, I don't want a sticky footer. That's why this is frustrating for me lol.

Comment: Then no need for `position: absolute` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `position:absolute`. This will cause your footer to be the last block-level element on the page. You can also remove your positioning attributes, `bottom, right, left`.

`positon: absolute` takes the element out of document flow -- elements will not regard it as "taking up space", which is why it appears to be floating on top of things.

```css
.rest-of-page {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 1000px;
}
.footer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rest-of-page"></div>
<div class="footer">I am the foot</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine. Except for when you go into the chrome developer console with f12 and use the responsive window then the footer doesn't even show except for the text and its not all the way at the bottom. Otherwise in full screen on a laptop even if you have to scroll it's at the bottom. Glitch maybe?

Comment: @dmberko11 could be a conflict with some of your other page styles/layout. This is pretty basic functionality so I'd be surprised if Chrome wasn't rendering stacked block elements properly, responsive preview or no!

Comment: I'll figure it out I hope. The footer works great on all pages in mobile or desktop view, scroll or not, except for the landing page on mobile. Lol. So close...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve something like in [this page](https://tracker.lugolabs.com/sign_in), where the footer is always at the bottom, without fixed heights. Here's my solution for it (using flex):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="site-content"></div>
  <div class="site-footer"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

You can then style the footer as you like, and it always be at the bottom. I have found that this is now a common solution to this problem.
The code for Tracker is open source on [Github](https://github.com/lugolabs/tracker).

Answer (score 0):

So after much research and trying it in my own projects, I want to share my formula. Not taking credit for it because I'm sure my methods are similar if not a carbon copy of what someone else has done but hey, if it helps you out, great!

I will say this: no matter how much content your views have or don't have, how big or small your viewport is, zooming in or out, the damn footer stays at the bottom!!

### Application.html.erb

```
<body>
    <div id="site_wrapper">
      <div id="site_content">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div id="footer"><h3>DMB Web Development, All Rights Reserved © 2019</h3></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

#### Application.scss

```
body {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}


#site_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

#site_content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: medium;
  border-top-color: #807B7A;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```